# How to inspect what data react table sends to filter function as argument?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I was looking at [filtering example](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/filtering) from react table filter table records. I wanted to see the data structure received in the following filter function. But my `console.log(..` not coming to browser console. How to check that? As per documentation, it should call the text function, but it is likely not calling.

```
function Table({ columns, data }) {
  const filterTypes = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      // Add a new fuzzyTextFilterFn filter type.
      fuzzyText: fuzzyTextFilterFn,
      // Or, override the default text filter to use
      // "startWith"
      text: (rows, id, filterValue) => {
        console.log(rows);
        return rows.filter((row) => {
          const rowValue = row.values[id];
          return rowValue !== undefined
            ? String(rowValue)
                .toLowerCase()
                .startsWith(String(filterValue).toLowerCase())
            : true;
        });
      }
    }),
    []
  );

//.....
```

Example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-mcnulty-fij1x?file=/src/App.js:5333-5952).

Answer (score 2):

React's useMemo hook returns a memoized version of your callback function's return object. It doesn't do anything else. *text* function won't get executed so you won't see the console.log. Another point is you're giving useMemo a empty dependency list. This means your memoized object never gets updated and it'll be out-of-sync probably.

Comment: Well. My point is when do the table search, the object text function will be called as per doc, so log should come. Please check my sanbox. I know it return memoized object, but object has functions, so they are there to be invoked right?

Comment: Oh, I see. Well if you decrease the number of rows to 1000 or something, it gets displayed in console. I think it doesn't show up in your sandbox for some performance issues.

Comment: Hm in my actual app it is not coming either.. Then I visited this example to see if it is same here.. So can you see it while reducing data size?

Comment: Yes I see the console with this sandbox; https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-ardinghelli-8pgez?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ok in my app I don't see it.  But with less data it comes to codesanbox yes.